# BizTalk generated wrong 999 file?

Tags: biztalk, biztalk-2013

I am working on a BizTalk inbound process to inbound 837-p files from different trading partners. After the file is processed inbound, I am also forwarding the BizTalk auto-generated 999 file to trading partners as an acknowledgement.

For a special trading partner, BizTalk inbound the 837 file and generated a 999 file claim all records in this file are "Accepted" in its AK9 segment.

But the continue process of these records from the file shows it have some records actually failed.

I saved one of the failed message as XML and validated it with the 837-p schema shipped with BizTalk, it actually failed in validation with following error:

> error BEC2004: The element 'PRV_BillingProviderSpecialtyInformation'
>   in namespace 'http://schemas.microsoft.com/BizTalk/EDI/X12/2006' has
>   incomplete content. List of possible elements expected:
>   'PRV03_ProviderTaxonomyCode'.

The question is, if the record actually failed in schema validation, why was the 999 generated with all records as "Accept"?

Some other info:

1. The EDI Validation is turned on in that trading partner's agreement.
2. I've double verified that all the setting in agreement are matching the 
   incoming file.
3. This validation is actually a HIPPA level 2 validation. But per BizTalk document, it should support level 2 validation.
4. The BizTalk version is BizTalk 2013 with CU3 update.

Comment: Where exactly did it fail downstream?  What exactly was the app doing at this point?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally figure it out. The missing element BizTalk complains is actually holds a single space character. So it passes the inbound validation, but the space char is trimmed later on in an orchestration. Then the error is raised.