# A catch 22 in generating 999 file

Tags: biztalk, edi

Well, I have to say it is kind of funny when I meet this situation:

I am inbounding HIPPA 837 files and I am suppose to create 999 ACK files once received the 837 file. BizTalk will generate the 999 message if I setup the  trading partner agreement to do so. And it works fine so far.

Today, I received a 837 file with some structure error: there are some leading space character in an element. Then the 999 was created, but when my send port subscribe this 999 message try to save it as a file, I got an validation error complains the 999 message itself is invalid cause its element have leading space characters.....

> Error: 3 (Field level error)
>   SegmentID: IK4
>   Position in TS: 18
>   Data Element ID: IK44
>   Position in Segment: 4
>   Data Value:
>   6: Leading or trailing space found

It looks for me like a catch 22: your 999 files are suppose to report structure error of the inbound file,**it will include the wrong element value as part of the report (in my case, it's in IK4 segment) , but the wrong element value itself make the 999 file invalid too.**

I just want to know if anyone have meet the same situation? And what's your suggestion on this issue?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [BizTalk generated wrong 999 file?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34278669/biztalk-generated-wrong-999-file)

Comment: @mahematd: You are wrong. Totally different problem

Comment: Both question asked by me. I am sure.

Comment: @Mathemats, If you are the one who downvote my question and mark it possible identify with another querstion(which is also my question). I'd like to see you correct your mistake.

Comment: They are completely different questions.

Answer (score 2):

I have not seen this, and really, I'm a bit surprised it hasn't come up before, if it's a real catch-22 :)

Try this, in the You->Them tab of the Agreement, set the Default row in the Validation section to have Leading and trailing spaces = Allowed.

You may have to explicitly set all other tx to Not Allowed since the 999 is not on the Transaction Type list.

Comment: Does this work?  I've frequently had issues with trying to use this functionality - if there are leading spaces in certain fields, the EDI runtime barfs even if these settings are in there.

Comment: The Default row is a bit sensitive and it's easy to 'confuse' it.  But, now that you mention it, I recall issues of that the leading/training spaces not always working so maybe there is a bug somewhere.

Answer (score 1):

I would try @Johns-305's suggestion, but I know I've had issues with using the allow leading/trailing spaces before in the agreement (some fields just seem to blow up on this for me even with it on).

I would try capturing the 999 message before it gets to the EDI send and using `normalize-space()` (in XSLT) or `.Trim()` (in C#) on the node(s) in question.  You can do this by creating a send port that filters on the 999 `BTS.MessageType`.

This may not fully satisfy your trading partner's expectations though, because the segment might be valid without a space (leading to confusion about why a perhaps otherwise valid segment was rejected).

You also might take this up with Microsoft, although it might be a limitation of using XML (where leading whitespace may be treated as insignificant) to represent EDI (where leading whitespace is bad news).